# How can I use Conditional Logic to set two variables in a python function and then use the function to set a new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, apply

If I had a function to set a variable based on some columns in a dataframe I can do it with conditional syntax and create the variable val. I can then create a new column using the apply function in pandas by applying this function to the dataframe df.

My question is am I able to use the conditional statement in the function to set 2 variables (val,val2) and then create two new columns 'fruit' and 'number' in Pandas using an apply function?

I can easily just create two functions and set val 1 and val 2 in each function and then have two separate apply functions to create the two columns, but I was wondering if I was able to do it in one function that sets both variables to reduce having to duplicate the code and one apply function?

Please let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Cheers

```
import pandas as pd

list_of_classes =[
['cit','lemon'],
['cit','lemon'],
['cit','lemon'],
['cit','lemon'], 
['watermelon','lemon'],
['watermelon','lemon'],
['lime','water'],    
['lime','water']
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_classes,columns = ['class','subclass'])

print(df)

def create_variables(row):
    if row['class'] == 'Lime':
        val = 'Lime'
        val2 = 1
        
    elif row['sub_class'] == 'lemon':
        val = 'lemon'
        val2 = 1.1
        
    elif row['sub_class'] == 'orange':
        val = 'orange'
        val2 = 1.2
        
    elif row['class'] == 'Apple':
        val = 'Apple'
        val2 = 2
               
    else:
        val = 'exception'
        val2 = 'exception'
        
    return val, val2
```

#create new column in dataframe 'df' for fruit and number

`df[['fruit', 'number']] = df.apply(create_variables, axis=1)`

The output I'm after with the two new columns would look something like below:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example input and the matching expected output? Also, is the order of the conditionals important?

Comment: Thanks I provided the example input and the expected output with the two columns. No Order isn't important in this case I'm fine with the actual conditional logic it's more creating the columns in the event the function creates multiple variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the `result_type` parameter of the [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function. Specifically, you want to use "expand" here:

> ‘expand’ : list-like results will be turned into columns.

Edit: Also the description of the behavior of the default `None` implies that if you modify your function to return a `pd.Series` then it will expand it into columns, e.g.:

```
return pd.Series([val,val2])
```